# Scrolling DataGridView with Mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So we are all familiar with the functionality of click and holding down the mouse button, then moving the mouse to the edge of a grid, and the columns/rows scroll and the selection grows.

I have a DataGridView-based control that I had to turn MultiSelect off and handle the selection process myself due to performance issues, and now the click+hold scrolling feature is disabled as well.

Any suggestions about how to go about writing back in this functionality?

I was thinking of using something simple like the MouseLeave event, but I'm not sure how to determine which position it left, as well as implementing a dynamic scroll speed.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? Can you put piece of code(if you have did anything)?

Comment: I have not done anything yet...I was hoping to get some (general) guidance on a reasonable way to approach this before coding it.

Answer (score 11):

Just add this code to your **Form1_Load**

```
DataGridView1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(DataGridView1_MouseWheel);
```

And this one is for the MouseWheel event

```
void DataGridView1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int currentIndex = this.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
    int scrollLines = SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines;

    if (e.Delta > 0) 
    {
        this.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex 
            = Math.Max(0, currentIndex - scrollLines);
    }
    else if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
        this.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex 
            = currentIndex + scrollLines;
    }
}
```

Comment: sometimes i got this System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 4):

Complete Answer
You need to set Focus Datagridview

```
private void DataGridView1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView1.Focus();
        }

then Add Mouse wheel event in Load function 
DataGridView1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(DataGridView1_MouseWheel);

Finally Create Mouse wheel function

void DataGridView1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int currentIndex = this.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
    int scrollLines = SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines;

    if (e.Delta > 0) 
    {
        this.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Math.Max(0, currentIndex - scrollLines);
    }
    else if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
        if (this.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > (currentIndex + scrollLines))
            this.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = currentIndex + scrollLines;
    }
}
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException will not occur if :

```
void DataGridView1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int currentIndex = this.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
    int scrollLines = SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines;

    if (e.Delta > 0) 
    {
        this.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Math.Max(0, currentIndex - scrollLines);
    }
    else if (e.Delta < 0)
    {
        if (this.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > (currentIndex + scrollLines))
            this.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = currentIndex + scrollLines;
    }
}
```