# No Event For MouseWheel on DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, events, scroll, datagridview

I would like to disable all mouse scrolling on my `DataGridView` because it occasionally leads to unpredictable crashes.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217063/scrolling-datagridview-with-mouse), it is suggested to add the event `MouseWheel` to my `DataGridView`. But I cannot find such event.

I am using *.Net Framework 4.5* and running on my application is´n `64-bit` mode. Where can I find this event if any. Otherwise is there a way that my `DataGridView` ignores all mouse scrolling?

Comment: Have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116684/how-to-make-the-scrollbar-note-scroll-when-the-mouse-wheel-event-happens-in-c-sh

Comment: It is there but not in the Desginer. Intellisense has it though..

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGridView` (System.Windows.Forms) should contain an event for MouseWheel.  Be sure you're using your variable name and not the class name.  For example:

This will work:

```
DataGridView myDataGridView = new DataGridView();
myDataGridView.MouseWheel += myDataGridView_MouseWheel;
```

This will NOT work:

```
DataGridView.MouseWheel += ...
```

Comment: Just to add a comment, I personally didn't see the property in the window, but it did come up in Intellisense as I was typing it out manually. Not sure why, but that could be why OP wasn't seeing it.

Comment: It's so strange because `MouseWheel` does not appear on my Intellisense, but when I write it, Visual Studio seems to recognize it. Why is it so hidden?

Comment: @Pedram, what do you mean it doesn't appear on your Intellisense but Visual Studio recognizes it? It doesn't even show when you type part of it out..?

Comment: @DangerZone no it does not. but when i completely type it, i get no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can find event on [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) msdn page, simply make sure to tick "Inherited" checkbox to see inherited members. In this case [`Control.MouseWheel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel.aspx).

As to

> because it occasionally leads to unpredictable crashes

maybe it worth to investigate it. If it happens on mouse scrolling it may happens due to some other reasons (e.g. scrolling with <kbd>PgUp</kbd><kbd>PgDown</kbd> keys).

Answer (score 0):

The mousewheel support for a DataGridView doesn't work properly in 64 or 32bit executables.

It often causes a corrupted render, and sometimes crashes your program.

Disable it by handling each of you DataGridView's MouseWheel manually.

Add the following method:

```
    void DisableMouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HandledMouseEventArgs h = (HandledMouseEventArgs)e;

        h.Handled = true;

    }
```

Bind the event in either the constructor for the form or in the form's Load event:

```
dgv.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(DisableMouseWheel);
```

Note: Replace dgv with the name of your own DataGridView.